# Crashing of my system

Tags: mesh

Am new in Blender but it keeps crashing whenever I'am in the shader editor.

My changes doesn't affect my mesh in the shader. How do I fix this?

Comment: Questions of this kind completely depend on system specifications, OS, graphic card used, processor, drivers updated or not, etc. It is only "my system" what is mentioned in your question instead. Edit it and clarify please what you use. So far wild guess is that your graphic card is not supported (probably you enter LookDev shading mode with Shader opened which requires new cards). Review https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ and see if your system matches them

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak.  I will get my spec soon